# Getting the right token for embedding PowerBi Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, powerbi-embedded

I am following this example to embed report in Angular 6 app. I need to make some tweeks to make it work on Angular 8.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-embed-powerbi-report-in-angular-6/

The last thing was the access token.

To get the short term token I used Postman with the following endpoint:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/38efd35e-da65-4e47-8656-876039ad15b1/oauth2/token

Where 38efd35e-da65-4e47-8656-876039ad15b1 is my TenantId.

I provided App ID and client_secret. The resource is https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api

I am able to generate token with the call.

The Report ID is in new Workspace. In the access control, app ID is added as administrator (Service Principal). In the code I am providing Report Id and Group ID.
The App has permission for Power Bi service.
When I use the token generated in Postman as access_token I get 403 error displayed in the Angular Console.

What I could be doing wrong? What is missing?
Is it a wrong Bearer Token? Should I use something else?

MS does not provide clear step by step guide for the process.

Preferably I would like to stick to Javascript/typescript stack and not involve .NET or C#.

Comment: What are you passing for grant_type? When grant_type is "authorization_code" you get back an access token. When grant_type is "refresh_token" its a refresh token and cannot be used to access anything

Comment: I am passing "Client_credentials" and using app's client_secret.

Comment: When I did what you suggested I am getting error:

Comment: "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'.\r\nTrace ID: 05c74ad7-6b22-4a80-bea5-bffa60143700\r\nCorrelation ID: b97d9bcd-9a9a-46f1-a6b5-3dd9114d1510\r\nTimestamp: 2019-11-26 08:07:59Z",

Comment: Okay cool stick with "client_credentials" I forgot that was one of the possible grant types. Next question, what are you passing for `scope`? I believe it should be `https://powerbi.microsoft.com/.default` check out this link for more details on `scope` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret

Comment: Thanks. Partial success. I was definitely passing the wrong scope. I get the token with TokenID (previously I ws getting Bearer. However the Angular code still produces "403" error while trying https://api.powerbi.com/powerbi/globalservice/v201606/clusterdetails

Comment: and also I see it tries to fetch https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=d7c20ea6-67af-41be-b9f6-af2839cab97e&uid=kxcb0 (What is this uid parameter anyway?)

Comment: I probably need to compile https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples

Comment: but the .csproj does not open on visual studio community on mac - I need to try this on Windows  to verify if everything is ok on the Azure side. What is annoying is that according to MS documentation creating an app for use with Service Principal with Embedding Tool, the bottom of the creator page says "this app cannot be used with service principal" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you are missing one step that is [generating embed token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/generatetoken) using access token that you have generated on Postman. Instead of using access token directly to embed your report, you need to use embed token because you are using Service Principal as a method for embedding.
And you also need to provide the type of token to be used for embedding in embed config as following:

```
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
var config = {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    id: embedReportId,
    settings: {}
};
```

Since 'service principal' and 'master user' falls under 'Embed for your customers' where embed token must be generated. Whereas, if you want to use only access token, you can use 'Embed for your organization' where user (with pro account) needs to sign-in (if not already) for generating access token.

You can refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedding) to understand embedding with Power BI.

There are two type of embedding, you can refer to these links:

1. [Embedding for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization)
2. [Embedding for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers)

You can also refer to this all new [sample created on React technology for 'embed for your organization' embed type](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/React-TS).